# How to call two functions in Firebase Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use one Cloud Function to resize images and the second on for uploading a new image URL to Cloud Firestore.

But something doesn't work, because the second function never runs.
I need the uid and postId where I can update the url.

How can I call the second function to update the img url in Firestore?

Code

```
const { functions, tmpdir, dirname, join, sharp, fse, gcs } = require('../../admin');

const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 120,
    memory: '1GB',
};

exports.resizeImages = functions
    .runWith(runtimeOpts)
    .storage.object()
    .onFinalize(async (object, context) => {
        const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
        const filePath = object.name;
        const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
        const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

        const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'resize');
        const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, 'source.png');

        if (fileName.includes('@s_') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
            return false;
        }

        await fse.ensureDir(workingDir);
        await bucket.file(filePath).download({ destination: tmpFilePath });

        // creates 3 new images with these sizes..
        const sizes = [1920, 720, 100];
        var newUrl = null;

        const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
            const ext = fileName.split('.').pop();
            const imgName = fileName.replace(`.${ext}`, '');
            const newImgName = `${imgName}@s_${size}.${ext}`;
            var imgPath = join(workingDir, newImgName);
            newUrl = imgPath;
            await sharp(tmpFilePath)
                .resize({ width: size })
                .toFile(imgPath);

            return bucket.upload(imgPath, {
                destination: join(bucketDir, newImgName),
            });
        });

        await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

      //second function

        functions.firestore.document('users/{uid}/posts/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
            console.log(context.params);
            const uid = context.params.uid;

            const userPost = functions.firestore.doc('users/{uid}/posts}');
            userPost.update({
                url: newUrl,
            });
        });

        return fse.remove(workingDir);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function appears to be embedded in the first.  This isn't going to work.  All function definition must be at the top level so they can be detected by the Firebase CLI and deployed separately.

If you don't actually want two separate function definitions, just perform all the work in one function, and don't try to use the functions SDK to do any of that work.  The Functions SDK is just for defining the functions for deployment.

Comment: and how can I get access to the user who uploaded the image? I need the uid from the user, how do I get the id?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question than the one you first asked.  In that case, please post a new question explaining what you're trying to do now.  If the answer to your question is satisfied by the answer here, please mark it as correct